# GetHashCode - Generate hash code from 64-bit address

Tags: c++-cli, gethashcode

We've got a 32-bit C++/CLI assembly and one of the classes wraps a native object. It overrides GetHashCode to return the address of the native object it wraps (m_native is a pointer):

```
int NativeWrapper::GetHashCode()
{
    return (int)m_native;
}
```

I'm now converting this assembly to support 64-bit, so the current GetHashCode implementation is no longer suitable. Are there any suitable algorithms to generate a hash code from a 64-bit address? Or am I missing an easier alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the same algorithm as the .Net framework does for generating the [hash code of an Int64](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int64.cs,db8a00a8905f817e): the lower 32 bits XORed with the upper 32 bits.

```
int NativeWrapper::GetHashCode()
{
    return ((int)m_native) ^ (int)(m_native >> 32);
}
```

Although, you could make a case for simple truncation: That's what [IntPtr.GetHashCode](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/intptr.cs,70891f34df7bf9d9) does.

If you want to support a dual 32/64 compile, perhaps casting `m_native` to `IntPtr` and using its GetHashCode would be a good implementation that works in both 32 and 64 bit modes.