# pointer truncation after x64 conversion

Tags: c++, visual-c++, 64-bit

I am new to C++ and I am trying to complie a small legacy class library that I always used as x86 for x64.

Now the compiler shows some warnings:

```cpp
            IUnknown* _p;
            // warning C4311: 'type cast': pointer truncation from 'IUnknown *' to 'int'
            // warning C4302: 'type cast': truncation from 'IUnknown *' to 'int'
            virtual int GetHashCode() override
            {
                return (int)_p;
            }

            // 1> warning C4311: 'type cast': pointer truncation from 'void *' to 'long'
            // 1> warning C4302: 'type cast': truncation from 'void *' to 'long'
            void MyMethod(IntPtr hwnd, String^ str)
            {
                CComBSTR bstrValue = (BSTR)Marshal::StringToBSTR(str).ToPointer();
                HRESULT result = SomeClass()->SomeMethod((long)hwnd.ToPointer(), bstrValue);
            }
```

where SomeMethod is defined as

```cpp
#ifdef _X86_
typedef long CUSTOMHWND;
#else
typedef LONGLONG CUSTOMHWND;
#endif

        virtual /* [helpstring][id] */ HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SomeMethod( 
            /* [in] */ CUSTOMHWND hwndOwner,
            /* [in] */ __RPC__in BSTR pValue) = 0;
```

How do I have to change the code to make it x64 safe?

Comment: Lessons on development of 64-bit C/C++ applications: https://www.viva64.com/en/l/full/ (Lesson 15. Pattern 7. Pointer packing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/common-visual-cpp-64-bit-migration-issues?view=vs-2019

- Use DWORD_PTR and LONG_PTR instead of long, int etc when referring to pointers (most Windows handles are pointers)
- When the application does not use LARGEADDRESSAWARE (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/largeaddressaware-handle-large-addresses?view=vs-2019) linker option, then all pointers are restricted to the lower 4GB so truncation will not harm. This is to save you time to fix all the warnings.

More migration tips: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinProg64/migration-tips

Comment: Thanks, I changed the second pice of code to `LONG_PTR`. 

For the first issue I found a link suggesting `return ((IntPtr)_p).GetHashCode();` instead. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37147711/98491

Also good to know that this wouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

In general, based on [[expr.cast]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cast#4), the C-style cast in

```
return (int)_p;
```

will end up performing a

```
return reinterpret_cast<int>(_p);
```

Now, strictly speaking, I believe that behavior in this case is actually unspecified. According to [[expr.reinterpret.cast]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#4):

> A pointer can be explicitly converted to any integral type large enough to hold all values of its type.

Note that the standard only specifies behavior here for the case of casting a pointer value to an integer type large enough to hold any possible value of that pointer type. I'm not aware of any wording in the standard that would specify behavior for the case of casting a pointer value to an integer type that is too small, which is what you're effectively doing here since `int` is not large enough (on MSVC) to represent a 64-Bit object pointer value. In practice, any compiler I've ever heard of will simply generate code that returns the lower 32 Bits (assuming `int` is 32 Bit wide) of the address that `_p` contains here, but you most likely shouldn't rely on that.

In general, I would simply avoid casting pointers to integers if you can. If you really have to, make sure to use integer types large enough to hold the pointer value. `std::intptr_t` or `std::uintptr_t` would be my first choice in that case.

All that being said, the name of your function would suggest that it's simply supposed to return a hash value, presumably to identify some object in a hash table. If that is the goal, I would recommend that you just use [`std::hash`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) to compute such a hash value for you rather than rely on casting pointers to integer values yourself:

```
        virtual std::size_t GetHashCode() override
        {
            return std::hash<IUnknown*>{}(_p);
        }
```

Let `std::hash` take care of getting a hash for an address for you. You can rely on that always doing whatver may be the the right thing to do to get such a hash, whatever the target platform may be…